# TinyMCE <p>&nbsp;</p><div id="ConnectiveDocSignExtentionInstalled" data-extension-version="1.0.4"></div>

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, tinymce

I have a MultiLine TextField in ASP.net VB with TinyMCE. A user of our website has a plugin on his computers that insert unwanted HTML code into the TinyMCE TextField.

```
<p>&nbsp;</p><div id="ConnectiveDocSignExtentionInstalled" data-extension-version="1.0.4"></div>
```

Is there a way to filter this text and remove it before saving the full textfield content to my SQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a TinyMCE node filter to remove the element when it serializes the content inside the editor. Here's an example:

```
setup: (editor) => {
  editor.on('PreInit',() => {
    // Create a custom node filter to remove unwanted content when getting content from the editor
    editor.serializer.addNodeFilter('div', (nodes) => {
      nodes.forEach((node) => {
        const id = node.attr('id');
        if (id === 'ConnectiveDocSignExtentionInstalled') {
          node.remove();
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

and a working version of it: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/RAhaab/1

This works by registering a filter during the initialization sequence to remove the offending div added by the users extension when TinyMCE fetches the content from the editor. More information about the Node API used by the filter can be found here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.html/tinymce.html.node/

Another option, that would depend on your integration, is to use server-side filtering of the content sent. How you do that would differ based on the frameworks, etc... being used.

Answer (score 0):

Came here just to say that this extra code is entered into text areas that process HTML when you have the "Connective Signing Extension" installed.

This extension gets installed when you use an electronic European ID card to log into government or banking services in the EU.

Today, I found their website and reported this behavior via their contact form.

I hope they respond, but I recommend others experiencing the same behavior please contact them and bubble up the bug!

Comment: I got a response from Connective EU today 12/16:
"This is fixed in the signing extension 1.0.5 which should be available in Production shortly."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).